# How to set background alpha for fxg in swf?

Tags: apache-flex, background, transparent, alpha

I loaded my fxg file from swf in my project. 
It's how i did this:

```
var loader:SWFLoader =new SWFLoader();
loader.load("output.swf");              
map.graphic.addElement(loader);
```

Background in fxg was transparent, but when i load this fxg from swf, background become white and not transparent. Please explain, how to set my background to transparent?
Here's my problem: 
[image]

Comment: If you load the SWF not through the SWFLoader; is the background trasnparent?  I'm unclear if the problem is with the FXG, the SWF code or with the loader.

Comment: I resolve my problem. My solution is to set backgroundalpha in mxml which compile in swf

Comment: Please post that as a formal answer to your question, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mxml with fxg to compile in swf:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
               creationComplete="application1_creationCompleteHandler()"
```

**backgroundAlpha="0"** >

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        {
            protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler():void
            {
                var layer:layer1_img = new layer1_img();        
                layer1_id.addElement(layer);
            }
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:Graphic id="layer1_id" scaleX="6.45" scaleY="6.45" height="873" width="541" x="3880" y="80"/>
</s:Application>
```